# AccessControl property - s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We have set following options amidst creation of bucket:

```
  PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
    BlockPublicAcls: true
    BlockPublicPolicy: true
    IgnorePublicAcls: true
    RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

to get below restriction for any user trying to change this option:

### [image]

We have also added below option:

```
  AccessControl: Private
```

where possible values are: `Private, PublicRead, PublicReadWrite, AuthenticatedRead, LogDeliveryWrite, BucketOwnerRead, BucketOwnerFullControl, or AwsExecRead`

---

This is a single zone VPC:

[image]

---

1) What is the meaning of `Private` vs `PublicRead`?

2) EC2 is created within VPC(by default). Is bucket created outside VPC? in public domain... Where is bucket created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Private` means that only owner has access to that resource, whether it is bucket or object, `PublicRead` means that resource owner still has full control but `allUsersGroup`, which means everyone, whether it is IAM user or not has read access to the resource. Both `Private` and `PublicRead` specify predefined set of grants or so called [canned ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl).

S3 bucket is not created in your VPC, it lives in AWS plane which is not part of your VPC. So by default, when you make S3 API call from within your VPC, the traffic goes through the Internet. If you need this traffic between resources in your VPC and S3 to go through private network then you need to place VPC Gateway Endpoint for S3 into your VPC and route the S3 traffic through it.

Here is a minimal template containing new VPC, one subnet, S3 VPC endpoint and route table for that subnet with route to S3 endpoint for S3 traffic.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:
    MyVPC:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
        Properties:
            CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
            EnableDnsHostnames: true
            EnableDnsSupport: true
    MySubnet:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
            CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
    MyRouteTable:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
    SubnetRouteTableAssociation:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
        Properties:
            RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable
            SubnetId: !Ref MySubnet
    S3Endpoint:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint'
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
            RouteTableIds:
                - !Ref MyRouteTable
            ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3
```

Comment: **1)** AWS plane? how it is different from VPC?

Comment: **2)** I want to understand more on setting VPC gateway endpoint for S3, because we want the traffic between VPC and S3 through private network. Can we specify this in Cloudformation template?

Comment: 1. simply put, it is network controlled by AWS through which you can access AWS services but you have no control over this network. VPC is under your control.

Comment: 2. You can specify it in CloudFormation, it is just another VPC resource - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html

Comment: Any reference to an cloudformation example to create a bucket with VPCendpoint?

Comment: S3 buckets and VPC endpoints are not really dependent on each other. Endpoint is part of your VPC so you will need to create several resources in your Template (or reference them) , at least VPC, subnets, route table, route for VPC endpoint and VPC endpoints itself. One you have that, all S3 traffic, independent on specific S3 bucket will be routed through the VPC endpoint. As for link to such template, unfortunately I don't have any but I can create it, I will update answer once I have it.

Comment: But if you use VPCgatewayendpoint then can you view this bucket in aws console?

Comment: I have added mentioned template. Yes you can still view S3 bucket from console, S3 endpoint has nothing to do with S3 buckets, it is a network component in your VPC through which you can route traffic.

Comment: Edited query with a single zone VPC. How does VPC end point work with S3 in that architecture? I would like to the see the picture

Comment: It is the same for single AZ and multi AZ in case of S3. All that matters here is `VpcId ` and `RouteTableIds ` where you specify which route tables should include entry for S3 endpoint.

Comment: Would you mind, to edit the diagram I uploaded? to visualize VPCEndPoint? am not able to visualize your Cfn template. Security concepts, for me, look complex to learn.

Comment: There are two types. Gateways which you can visualize in the same way as IGW or NAT Gateway but instead of routing to the Internet, it routes to AWS network -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html. Second one is Interface which you can visualize just as EC2 instance. It is just ENI that sits in your subnet in the same way EC2 instance sits in your subnet.

Comment: I did not get you, when you say: "`Private` means that only owner has access to that resource"..... Being a `crossaccountrole` in account `xyz`... I created this bucket. Now, `aws cli` is trying to access this bucket from an EC2. To get access, I had to create a EC2 role and allow s3 read write access. So, when you say, owner has access.... Do you mean `aws cli` needs to run as `--profile xyz`?

Comment: Owner as an account that owns it. Cross-account role has nothing to do with it because by assuming cross-account role, you are becoming entity in that account so there is no ownership mismatch. Well, if you have created S3 bucket in `xyz` then obviously you need to use credentials that grant access to that account/bucket. Therefore yes, if we both mean the same by `--profile xyz`